# How to pass object data of table row from one component to another component

Tags: angular, frontend

I have a mat table on my one component and after clicking on particular row that information should be displayed to another component. I am able to console information on my first page but not able to move that information to another page. for exmample "console.log(row)".
Entire information is in "row" parameter

And how i can print it on my new component page with key and value format

Comment: If I understand correctly then all you need is, to pass `row` parameter as a prop to your child component where you need.

Comment: This link https://www.codementor.io/@theparam/angular-sharing-data-between-components-tw78psu75 might help you.

Comment: @MilindAgrawal actully i am able to see all the row information in the key-value format on my console on my first component like this: vendorID: 122, vendorName: "123", category: "ABC", date: "10/01/2019", lastActive: "20/01/2019"}

But i want to show it on another component of my "Component" not on console

Comment: Can you share some code to understand your situation better ?

Comment: @MilindAgrawal

vendor-total.component.html

 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="vendorDisplayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr (click)="displayData(row)" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: vendorDisplayedColumns;"></tr>

vendor-total.component.ts

displayData(row)
  {
    console.log(row);
    this.router.navigate(["/home/vendor-total/details"]);
  }

I want to display this data of "row" which is displaying on console in the form of Key and value pair on the Details component

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Input decorator. Following is minimal example and [here is the docs.](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-child',
  template: `
    <p>{{masterName}}</p>
  `
})
export class HeroChildComponent {
  @Input('master') masterName: string; // extracts master attribute
}
```

and parent component

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-parent',
  template: `
    <app-hero-child
      [master]="master"> // send string to child component
    </app-hero-child>
  `
})
export class HeroParentComponent {
  master = 'Master';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a click function on the row :

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of list" (click)="navigate(item)">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Use this function to navigate to another route passing a state :

```
navigate(item): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/item'], {state: {item: item}});
  }
```

Retrieve the state with `history` into the other component (no import required) :

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(history.state);
  }
```